# Is there is anything equivalent to recyclerview in xamarin Ios?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am native android developer and I know well that how to use Recyclerview and a Single view of recycler view,

Same I want in Ios, I did some search and I found that I can use Collection View in place of recyclerview,

But my concern is that Recyclerview Can use any kind of a single view, means we can custmize our single view with drag and drop of UI,

same thing How can i achieve in UI collectionview cells?

I found way to custmize cells through code, but I dont want to go through code to custmize it, I also found that Cells are having only square shape,

How can i make rectangular shape or How can i fully custmize my cells?

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i fully custmize my cells

In the following [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance/#Custom_Cells) you can find how to create custom cells.

One easy way is using XAML and the `ItemTemplate` property. From the documentation:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
            Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding image}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding title}"
                    TextColor="#f35e20" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding subtitle}"
                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                    TextColor="#503026" />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

You can also create a cell from C# if you inherit from `ViewCell`

I hope this can help you.